# Progress Bar when function is running

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have a `SignUp` function, called when a button is clicked. In the `onClickListener` function, it is called like this:

```
SignUp(Uname.getText().toString(), Pword.getText().toString(),
        Umail.getText().toString());
```

While the function is running, I need to show a progress bar. How can I do this?

Here is the code for the `SignUp()` function:

```
public void  SignUp (String Username, String Password, String Email) {
    Integer Userch = CheckUName (Username);
    Integer UserMl = CheckUMail (Email);

    if (Userch == 3)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "این نام کاربری قبلا ثبت شده است",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
    else if (UserMl == 3)
       {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "این پست الکترونیکی قبلا ثبت شده است", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
       }
       else if ((UserMl == 4) && (Userch == 4))
       {

                String Pass = null;
                InputStream is = null;
                String result = "";
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UUName", Username));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UPWord", Password));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UMail", Email));

                try{

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SignupAddress);
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ثبت نام انجام شد", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        

                }catch(Exception e){

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                } 
       }


    }
```

edited for libin :
    how i call :

```
 public void onClick(View v)
            {

                mProgressDialog.show();

                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

                String Result = login(Username.getText().toString());

                if (Username.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "نام کاربری را وارد کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mProgressDialog.hide();

                }
                else if  (Password.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "کلمه عبور را وارد کنید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                    mProgressDialog.hide();

                }
                else
                {

                        if (Result.equals(Password.getText().toString()))
                         {

                            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), HomePage.class);
                             i.putExtra("new_variable_name",Username.getText().toString());
                             startActivity(i);

                         }
                         else if (Result == "Wrong Username or Password")
                         {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();

                              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "نام کاربری یا کلمه عبور اشتباه است", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
                         }
                          else if (Result == "Error Connection")
                         {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();

                              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "مشکلی در برقراری ارتباط وجود دارد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
                         }
                          else if (Result == "Convert Error")
                         {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();

                              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "مشکلی بوجود آمده است", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
                         }
                          else 
                         {
                            mProgressDialog.hide();

                              Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "نام کاربری یا کلمه عبور اشتباه است", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
                          }
                    }


            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of `ProgressDialog` in  `onCreate()` of `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
  private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

  mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing In...");
```

When you click the button call,

```
  mProgressDialog.show();
```

And , When you get the response back from `HTTP Request` , call

```
 mProgressDialog.hide();
```

And in Activity `onDestroy` , dismiss the dialog

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    if (mProgressDialog != null) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

If your are execute the network request in an AsyncTask . You can show the progress in `onPreExecute() and hide in`onPostExecute()`

Comment: but i need progress Bar. when i click button , progress dialog is not showing, just application freezes until it do the job, its work only when activity is changing

Comment: can  u post your code how you call the show and hide?

Comment: ok, i edited my post. i need to show progress dialog or bar when it is connecting and signing up, not when a hardware job is running.

Comment: Why do you hide it in multiple places? I think something wrong in logic hide is called immediately after show. Try to remove all the hide() call and see if you see the progress dialog

Comment: i did test every where, its not because of its place, i need a Thread and runnable method. i searched, but didnt find a good example.

Comment: Try to use  AsyncTask

Comment: i dont know about aysyncTask, searching now.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305588/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-how-to-solve-it/23305830#23305830

Comment: thank you, now i know i have to use AsyncTask, i just dont get it. i have to search more.