# What is the best way to solve android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

I am trying to put the file throght webdav in android,

after i execute the program, the Logcat appear android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

i had try two ways to sloves it, likes the code below

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

and this one

```
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()  
        .detectDiskReads()  
        .detectDiskWrites()  
        .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems  
        .penaltyLog()  
        .build());  
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()  
        .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()  
        .detectLeakedClosableObjects()  
        .penaltyLog()  
        .penaltyDeath()  
        .build());
```

it could work but those ways force my project to close,

so i thought its not good ways to use on my project

after that i had been researched on it,

everyone recommended this way to solve it

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305588/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-how-to-solve-it)

But i am beginner i dont know how to fill my code in,

I would like to know how could I fill in my code in this way,

Thank you in advance for any assistance that can be provided here.

```
         loginConfirmBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                        getIpAddress = ipAddress.getText().toString().trim();
                        getUserName = userName.getText().toString().trim();
                        getPassWord = passWord.getText().toString().trim();

                        uploadFiles(sourceFilePath);

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "upload suseeful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        hideKeyboard();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "make sure you have connected the internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                          
           }

        public void uploadFiles(String dir){
            Log.d("edoc","PutRunGenuine");
            String fileFromEscan = dir;

            Conn conn_adv = new Conn(new Constants(getUserName, getPassWord, getIpAddress, 80));                                conn_adv.setUrl("/collab/my/"+conn_adv.getUser()+"/sourceFilePath2");
            Log.d("edoc","edoc test");
               if (fileFromEscan == null) 
               {
                   return;
               }
               try {                 
               String putAvg = "PUT avg: ";
               ExtractedMethod exm =  new ExtractedMethod();
               exm.run(HTCode.Code.PUT, 1, conn_adv, true, fileFromEscan, 1000, true);

               Log.d("edoc","edoc_message hello");
               synchronized(conn_adv){
                   conn_adv.notify();                           
               }

               } catch (Exception io) {
                   io.printStackTrace();
                   Log.d("edoc","edoc Exception"+io);
                 }
           }
```

Comment: do the "job" inside an asynctask

Comment: look at the 2nd answer in the SO post you given

Comment: Either do the network task in AsyncTask or run the network code in new thread.

Comment: Just for clarification. NetworkOnMainThreadException is not thrown without reason. Network operations are restricted by Android because it's really a bad practice. Use AsyncTask class or threads as suggested above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Means that you are doing some `Network job` in the `MainThread`. However any Networking job should be done in other thread than the `Main(UI Thread)`

You have to move `uploadFiles(sourceFilePath);` *method* to the `BackgroundThread`. As some suggested on the comments you can use `AsyncTask` and move that *method* to `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 0):

hungwei0331,

You have to do your work inside `doInBackground()` function of async task.
Because, **`Network operations are time-consuming so you can't  execute this function on activity thread.`**

Solution is to use `asyncTask` or `thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **AsyncTask** and perform your network operations in its **doInBackground**.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is Thread with join. It's ugly but workable.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //do all here
    });
  }
});

t.Start();
t.Join();
```